# Does the #Predicate macro in Foundation/SwiftData support case-insensitive search?

Tags: swift, predicate, swift-data

I'm testing the new SwifData framework and working with the new #Predicate macro and realized that it doesn't support case-insensitive search. The macro does not work with the lowercased() method or the localizedLowercase property, so there seems to be no way to create a case-insensitive predicate, as we used to do with NSPredicate and the [c] attribute.

```
   var predicate = #Predicate<Book> {
  $0.title.localized().contains(search) }
```

Error: The lowercased() function is not supported in this predicate (from macro 'Predicate')

I wonder if there is any work around.
Thanks

Comment: You're not alone: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/733215

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The new `Predicate` macro works pretty well with the `localizedStandardContains(_:)` function.

[From the Apple dev documentation website](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/stringprotocol/localizedstandardcontains(_:)):

> This is the most appropriate method for doing user-level string searches, similar to how searches are done generally in the system. **The search is locale-aware, case and diacritic insensitive.** The exact list of search options applied may change over time.

Usage:

```
let userInput = "foo bar"
let predicate = #Predicate<Book> { $0.title.localizedStandardContains(userInput) }
```

Comment: Thanks. I noticed that on Xcode Beta 6 a few days ago. This is the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**
As pointed out by Mikiko Jane, this works only in a filter predicate for an array, not in a `@Query` directly.

I attempted to use a `@Transient` field to make it lower case on the fly

```
@Transient
var nameNormalized: String {
    name.lowercased()
}
```

The predicate could not see the transient property, as I assume it's looking for only things persisted to the database.

I suppose the only solution currently is to create a field that updates whenever the first field updates.  This is a lot of overhead and boiler plate to just have a proper search functionality.  This seems to explicitly go against the goals of SwiftData.

**Original answer**

---

I've played around with this, trying a lot of solutions, but I might have found a way to do case insensitive compare.  In the SwiftData SampleTrips sample project I changed

```
let filteredList = try? trip.bucketList.filter(#Predicate { item in
    item.title.contains(searchText) && tripName == item.trip?.name
})
```

to:

```
let filteredList = try? trip.bucketList.filter(#Predicate { item in
    return item.title.localizedLowercase.contains(searchText.localizedLowercase) && tripName == item.trip?.name
})
```

This seemed to work.  It seems the macro has support for `localizedLowercase` but not for `lowerCased()`

Comment: There is even [localizedCaseInsensitiveContains](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1412098-localizedcaseinsensitivecontains) which avoids the second `localizedLowercase` call.

Comment: Hi, guys. Unfortunately, the localizedLowercase property returns an error when you use it to search for objects in the database, and the localizedCaseInsensitiveContains() method keeps giving the error "function is not supported in this predicate". The localizedLowecase property may work in the SampleTrips app because the predicate is used to search in an array, but the property is turned into a key path by the macro and therefore when you use it to search in the database, SwiftData tries to find a property with that name in the class, returns an error, and the app crashes.

Comment: Ugh, that's unfortunate that it seems to work when the predicate is filtering, a list, but not for a @Query.

Comment: The solution you mention in the update is the one I'm currently using.  I hope they add native support later. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Just to clarify. I'm not using a Transient property, I just added another property to the model to store the string in lower case, and search that property instead of the original.

Comment: Yeah, its not great to have to mirror every searchable field in another field, doubling storage and adding boilerplate code, which is sort of the antithesis of SwiftData